# Getting Data out of Union Class Crashes Python

Tags: python, pointers, structure, union, ctypes

I have wrapped a c library, and c API's in python and called the necessary DLL's. However I'm having trouble accessing my data that is stored inside of a union.

This is an example of what my wrapped library looks like(shortened for convienence):

```
import ctypes 
from ctypes import *
import pandas as pd

class Data(Union):
    _fields_ = [
         ('A', POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte)),
         ('B', POINTER(ctypes.c_float))]

class Parm(Structure):
    pass

class File(Structure):
     pass

Parm._fields_ = [
        ('parent', ctypes.POINTER(File)),
        ('name', ctypes.c_char_p),
        ('data', POINTER(Data)),
        ('time', ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float)),

File._fields_ = [
        ('name', ctypes.c_char_p),
        ('header', ctypes.POINTER(Header)), 
        ('fileInfo', ctypes.POINTER(FileInfo)),

 MultiF = (b'path_to_file')   
 dll = CDLL('path_to_dll') 

#read  functions
dll.openFile.argtypes = (c_char_p,)
dll.openFile.restype = POINTER(File)
dll.freeFile.argtypes = POINTER(File),
dll.freeFile.restype = int
F = dll.openFile(MultiF) # Pointer to File

ParmName = ctypes.c_char_p(b'parameter_name')
beginTime = ctypes.c_double(-3.4**38)
endTime = ctypes.c_double(3.4**38)
DT_FLOAT = 0x0001
DT_RETURNGMT = 0x0100
convertType = (DT_FLOAT|DT_RETURNGMT)

#retrieve parameter data
dll.readParm.argtypes = POINTER(File), c_char_p, c_double, c_double, POINTER(c_double), POINTER(TTag), c_ushort,
dll.readParm.restype = POINTER(Parm)
dll.freeParm.argtypes = POINTER(Parm),
dll.freeParm.restype = int
g = dll.readParm(F, ParmName, beginTime, endTime, None, None, convertType)
```

I'm able to retrieve the location of the time values with this pointer:

```
(g[0].time)
```

which returns:

```
<ctypes.wintypes.LP_c_float at 0x218f044aec8>
```

When I want to retrieve the location of the data values I type this:

```
(g[0].data[0].B)
```

which returns:

```
<ctypes.wintypes.LP_c_float at 0x218f044a9c8>
```

Now I want the actual time and data values so I created a for loop that should print out each time value and the corresponding data 
value for that time.

Here is my for loop:

```
x = []
y = []
for i in range(0, 1033):
    x.append(g[0].time[i])
    y.append(g[0].data[0].B[i])
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': x, 'Data': y})
df
```

But this crashed Python, but 'crash' I mean a box popped up and said Python is no longer working close now.

So I tried to figure out what the problem was and I found this:
    I can print out all values of time individually like so

```
print(g[0].time[0])
print(g[0].time[1])  #.....
```

Which returns:

```
7.304020881652832
7.352021217346191
```

These values are correct so I tried the same thing with the data values:

```
print(g[0].data[0].B[1])
```

and that's as far as I got because that crashed python.

The line that is crashing python is a pointer to a float in a Union that holds all of my data values.

## My question is this:

What am i doing wrong and how can I get my data out of this Union without crashing Python?

This is the C code I have for Parm and Data:

```
#define CBASED
#ifdef MAKEDLL 
#  define DLLEXP __declspec( dllexport ) 
//#  define CBASED
#  define CALLCONV
#else
/* using .H file for application */
#  define DLLEXP
/* ANSI C program */
#  ifdef __STDC__
//#    define CBASED
#    define CALLCONV
#  else
/* C++ program */
//#    define CBASED extern "C"
#    define CALLCONV _cdecl
#  endif 
#endif

//union Data
//{ 
//  unsigned char      *A;        /* generic byte pointer 1 byte        */
//  float              *B;        /* generic float pointer 4 byte       */

 //CBASED DLLEXP struct Parm
//{
//  struct File      *parent;         /* parent file of parameter    */
//  char             *name,           /* parameter name              */
//  union  Data       data;           /* pointers to data buffer     */
//  float             *time;           /* time points                 */
```

Comment: Please include the C definitions of `Parm` and `Data`.

Comment: @eryksun I added the C code

Comment: `('data', POINTER(Data)` is incorrect. The C definition is `union Data`, not `union Data *` . Use `('data', Data)`.

Comment: Then use `y = g[0].data.B[:1033]` to list the float data. Don't use a loop. It's slow.

Comment: Thank you that worked. If you want to make that an answer i'll accept it @eryksun